# Can't identify this Chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I am new to this forum. I found these chips on old motherboard that i was going to throw away, I salvaged these chips but Google Search could't help me to identify these.

Only Information i could find was this: http://www.bios-chip24.com/Winbond-25X40VAIZ-4MBit-SPI-Flash-DIP-8-300mil/en

Are they programmable? or just a junk?
Images:
https://ibb.co/VBTP15P
https://ibb.co/LN833ZK
https://ibb.co/3TpDVs4
Thank you.

Comment: throw them away. Seriously. You having chips for less than 0.1€ in worth isn't worth for you or us to look into this. Believe me, I used to salvage a lot of components, too, and that quickly accumulated to quite a bit of cruft. Throwing them out years later after I used exactly none of the salvaged chip was a great relief. So, don't even start collecting old ICs. What would you do with an ancient EEPROM? Save 40ct not buying an EEPROM when designing a new device? Certainly not.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The Thing is not being a cheapskate. I want to research anything i could find. So The real thing is are those useful?

Comment: no, they aren't. I answered exactly that in my first comment.

Comment: While learning about "old" stuff may seem beneficial, it's not really practical today.  In the time you'd invest in learning how to use some obscure chip from the 80's, you could find a much-better performing one today for pennies and have complete datasheets, vendors, and peace-of-mind knowing it is new and functional. At least until the magic smoke is let out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datasheet was on hackaday, they are programmable and large 128M-bit, might be useful for a project. Check the timing and make sure there are minimum clock speeds. If the minimum clock speed is faster than 30MHz you may have issued prot0yping with it.

> 1. GENERAL DESCRIPTIONS The W25Q128FV (128M-bit) Serial Flash memory provides a storage solution for systems with limited space, pins and
>      power. The 250 series offers flexibility and performance well beyond
>      ordinary Serial Flash devices. They are ideal for code shadowing to
>      RAM, executing code directly from Dual/Quad SPI (XIP) and storing
>      voice, text and data. The device operates on a single 2.7V to 3.6V
>      power supply with current consumption as low as 4mA active and 1uA for
>      power-down. All devices are offered in space-saving packages.

Source: https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/7758331918272/W25Q128F.pdf

Comment: What about this one: https://ibb.co/LN833ZK

Comment: 25F80? Looks like another SPI flash chip.